# Php code of a form not working. Code Stated here

Tags: php, html, web

The code of the Form is :-

```
  <form action="mail.php">
  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="name" value="Your Name *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="email" value="Your E-mail *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
  <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="message" cols="0" rows="0" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Your Message *</textarea>
  <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="send message">
  </form>
```

i have hosted the webpage but the form is not working. what else do I need to do to put it in functioning.

here is the php code:-

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'xyz@abc.com.com';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
empty($_POST['email']) ||
empty($_POST['message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if (!preg_match("/ ^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
$email_address))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}
if( empty($errors))
{
$to = '$myemail';
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
    "Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'indes' page
header('Location: index.html');
}
?>
```

I have done the php part and uploaded it to the website too but still it doesn't send any mail from the contact form. i.e. it is not responding at all. Can I get any help now ?

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: y r u using `class="form"; action="mail.php";` semicolon here? can u plz share the errors. otherwise no one can help u, share your PHP code also

Comment: I am not getting any comment at all. Problem is I need to fetch the data from here and mail it across to my email. How can I execute this task with any amount of change to this code

Comment: is there any PHP code ? if yes, please share

Comment: Please share your PHP code as well

Comment: Edited and added PHP code. Kindly review.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a way of collecting the submission when it is sent.  Have a read through this site, will provide you with more information.

Essentially you need to have use something like PHP to collect the information and process it, either store it into a database or email it to yourself.

[HTML & PHP Contact Form](http://1stwebdesigner.com/php-contact-form-html/)

mail.php

```
<?php
   $name    = $_POST['name'];
   $email   = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];

   $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
   $subject = 'the subject';
   $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
              'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?> 

   // Either insert into database or email to yourself.  You would want to look at sanitizing the inputs a bit and checking for valid email addresses.
```

[PHP mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)